# I can't implement DisplayPrompt in my sample project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I refer Xamarin.Forms docs. the link add below
[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups#display-a-prompt)
Please anyone has a solution Please help me
* **DisplayPrompt** implementation

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="tEST.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20">
    <Label Text="Display Prompt"
           FontSize="Large"
           HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Button Text="Question 1"
            Clicked="OnQuestion1ButtonClicked" />
    <Label x:Name="question1ResultLabel" />
    <Button Text="Question 2"
            Clicked="OnQuestion2ButtonClicked" />
    <Label x:Name="question2ResultLabel" />
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

C#

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace tEST
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void OnQuestion1ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's your name?");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
            question1ResultLabel.Text = $"Hello {result}.";
        }
    }

    async void OnQuestion2ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 2", "What's 5 + 5?", maxLength: 2, keyboard: Keyboard.Numeric);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result))
        {
            int number = Convert.ToInt32(result);
            question2ResultLabel.Text = number == 10 ? "Correct." : "Incorrect.";
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Getting errors:**

> **1**.CS0103  The name 'DisplayPromptAsync' does not exist in the current context
>
> **2**.Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State Error     The "FilterAssemblies" task failed
>   unexpectedly. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Users\Sharjas K
>   M\source\repos\tEST\tEST\tEST\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\tEST.dll'. File
>   name: 'C:\Users\Sharjas K
>   M\source\repos\tEST\tEST\tEST\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\tEST.dll'    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.FilterAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note: `DisplayPromptAsync` is feature of Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0**

If you want to show `alert`

```
bool result= await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Continue..", "Yes", "No");
```

If you want to take input from user

```
string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's your name?");
```

Where `result` you return you value entered by user.

Comment: I refer this site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/pop-ups

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: I can't build my project

Comment: My liveshare invitation code:  https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?AD64AD0414E22D449F51680C159C3F682E54

Comment: Hi bro..I can't open live share. It's not allowed. pl edit your question add code, add errors.. then I will check.

Comment: DisplayPromptAsync is feature of `Xamarin.Forms 4.3.0`. in your project go to Nuget package manager and update Xamarin.Forms dll.

Comment: I don't have a minimum reputation . I have 13 reputation only

Comment: This I have shown. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203611/discussion-between-sharjas-and-arvind-chourasiya).

Answer (score 3):

**`DisplayPrompt`** is available after XF 4.3 . So you could firstly update the version of Xamarin.Forms in Nuget . Then delete the folder `bin` and `obj` in your share project. Then clean and rebuild it.

[image]

**Note:** The DisplayPromptAsync method is currently only implemented on iOS and Android(So in UWP you could not call it).

Comment: What about MacOS? When I try `DisplayPromptAsync` nothing displays.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made `Xamarin.Forms` not updated. `DisplayPromptAsync` is a recent addition. You may need to update the `Xamarin.Forms` **version 4.3.0.991221** NuGet package.DisplayPromptAsync is not yet implemented on UWP.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer , which will help more people :)

Comment: I didn't notice sorry and Thanks

Comment: Happy coding :)